# How to monit disk I/O with monit?

Tags: linux, io, disk, system-administration, monit

Currently I'm using `M/Monit` to monitor a lot of instances at once. But Iwould also like to know if anyone tried to monitor Disk I/O with monit? I don't have any good knowledge about disks, so if someone could point me to the right direction or share some shell script would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is what you're looking for:

```
check filesystem datafs with path /dev/sdb1
 group server
 start program  = "/bin/mount /data"
 stop program  =  "/bin/umount /data"
 if failed permission 660 then unmonitor
 if failed uid root then unmonitor
 if failed gid disk then unmonitor
 if space usage > 80 % then alert
 if space usage > 94 % then stop
 if inode usage > 80 % then alert
 if inode usage > 94 % then stop
 alert root@localhost
```

Taken from: http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#examples

Answer (score 4):

You should be looking for CPU Wait, since that would be your biggest indicator of I/O wait issues:

```
check system $HOST
   if loadavg (15min) > 6 then alert
   if memory usage > 90% then alert
   if swap usage > 5% then alert
   if cpu usage (user) > 70% then alert
   if cpu usage (system) > 30% then alert
   if cpu usage (wait) > 30% then alert
   group system_resources
```